# c++ I met some problems using constriants and requires sentence to select overloaded function in a class template

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

```
template<typename T>
class Draw {
private:
    vector<vector<T> > map;

    template<typename T1 = T> 
    requires is_same_v<T, char>
    void draw(int x, int y) {
        map[19 - y][x] = '1';
    }

    template<typename T1 = T>
    requires is_same_v<T, bool>
    void draw(int x, int y) {
        map[19 - y][x] = false;
    }

public:

    template<typename T1 = T> requires is_same_v<T, char>
    Draw() :map(20, vector<char>(20, '0')) {};

    template<typename T1 = T> requires is_same_v<T, bool>
    Draw() :map(20, vector<bool>(20, false)) {};
```

I want to make the first function be called when T is char while the other called when T is bool.
But the compiler gives error "Unrecognized template declarations" ( visual studio C2988 )

Comment: concepts is a feature of C++20, you should use `/std:c++latest` flag for MSVC.

Comment: @康桓瑋 yes,it has been solved like that

Comment: Is there any reason for the `T1` template? I would use the simpler `void draw(int x, int y) requires is_same_v<T, char> { ... }`

Comment: @chi no,i eventually take the simpler way and it can work